# "И тот, и другой" — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Что-то меня заклинило (вот оно — горе от ума): "и тот(,) и другой" — нужна тут запятая или нет в предложениях типа "И тот(,) и другой жили на одной улице, поэтому часто встречались". Является ли тут этот оборот перечислением с союзом И?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь "и тот и другой" цельное  выражение, поэтому запятая не ставится.

Comment: А если так: " и тому, и другому дала кашки сорока"? Неужто это "нецельное выражение"? Или тут запятая тоже не нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, здесь могут быть варианты, все зависит от задумки автора. В нашем примере без контекста я бы поставила запятую, т. к. какого-либо обобщения в принципе нет, речь идет о двух разных персонах, все воспринимается буквально. Если бы была идея характеристики этих персонажей как во многом похожих, у которых есть много общего, тогда запятая бы не понадобилась. Мне кажется, не всегда следует приравнивать "и тот и другой" к "оба", "каждый", иногда есть смысл подчеркнуть такие ОЧП по отдельности, как и в примере с сорокой.

Answer (score 1):

При однородных членах предложения с  повторяющимся союзом "и"  запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): Кругом было и светло и зелено  (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму  старую жокейскую кепку  (Пауст.);

При наличии пояснительных слов запятая в этих случаях ОБЫЧНО ставится, например: …В вашем сердце есть и гордость, и прямая честь (Пушкин);

§ 70. Собственно факультативные знаки препинания

1. Факультативна постановка запятой между двумя однородными членами предложения с повторяющимся союзом и: Можно отдохнуть и в горах (,) и на берегу моря (см. § 13, п. 2).